# C++ template variable that isn't static

Tags: c++, templates

According to research that I did, I'm aware that I need to make this static for it to work in a class scope.

```
//Source.h
class Source
{
public: 
  template <class T>
  tst <T> foo;
  
  //static tst <T> foo;//<-- this works.. but static means only one instance of it
private:

};
```

But is there a way to do this without making it static? I'm pretty new to templates and the idea is based of a java Project I had. I need a variable of any specific type to be stored depending on how the class is instantiated and I also don't want it to be static because I need the values to stay after changing it.

Comment: sorry! i updated the question.. expected parameters would be either int, string, or class.

Comment: What if you put the template parameter on the `Source` class?  Then the variable can be that type without being static.

Comment: You'll need to make T a template parameter of `Source`

Comment: And if you don't want `Source` to be a class template, I think you'll have to use `std::any foo;` or something similar.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I did that earlier, but it basically just pushed the same problem elsewhere in the other class that I'm Creating Source. So instead id have to make that class static. Its a pretty big project also so I'm trying to not make too many drastic changes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I honestly wasn't aware std::any. Many thanks for the suggestions everyone, i'll do some more reading on std::any. It seems like what i want

Comment: Template parameters must be resolvable at compile-time ,  if you need different behaviour at runtime then a variant (i.e. `variant` or `any`) would be the good option, yes